# OData Services and Silverlight Client Side using different object than the Server Side, can I do it?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, odata

I am working on WP7 app (based on ODataWPNorthwindSample from MSDN)using the ODATA v2 library with DataServiceState class
In this example I have  MainViewModel.cs class where

```
> DataServiceCollection<Customer> customers;
> 
>   public DataServiceCollection<Customer> Customers 
>         {
>             get { return this.customers; }
> 
>             private set
>             {
>                 this.customers = value;
>                 
>                 this.customers.LoadCompleted +=
> this.OnCustomersLoaded;
>                 this.customers.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => {
> this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomersTitle"); };
> 
>                 this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Customers");
>                 this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomersTitle");
>             }
>         }
```

Where the Customer class has some attributes(very short version of it)is:

```
> public partial class Customer :
> global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
>     {
>         
>        
> [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design",
> "1.0.0")]
>         public static Customer CreateCustomer(string customerID,
> string companyName)
>         {
>             Customer customer = new Customer();
>             customer.CustomerID = customerID;
>             customer.CompanyName = companyName;
>             return customer;
>         }
> 
> [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design",
> "1.0.0")]
>         public string Address
>         {
>             get
>             {
>                 return this._Address;
>             }
>             set
>             {
>                 this.OnAddressChanging(value);
>                 this._Address = value;
>                 this.OnAddressChanged();
>                 this.OnPropertyChanged("Address");
>             }
>         }
>        
> [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design",
> "1.0.0")]
>         private string _Address;
>         partial void OnAddressChanging(string value);
>

     partial void OnAddressChanged();
```

For some reason I need to add one more attribute “AddressLocal” which will be used only on the client side and bind it to the XAML. The value of the “AddressLocal” I calculate based on “Address” attribute. So, if “Address” is changed “AddressLocal” will change also.

```
>  public string AddressLocal
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return this._ AddressLocal;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             this.On AddressLocal Changing(value);
>             this._AddressLocal = value;
>             this.OnAddressLocal Changed();
>             this.OnPropertyChanged("AddressLocal ");
>         }
>     }
>     
>     private string _AddressLocal;
>     partial void OnAddressLocal Changing(string value);
>     partial void OnAddressLocal Changed();
```

But this attribute does not exist in the database on the server and I don’t  need them there, but when I call

```
> App.ViewModel.Context.BeginSaveChanges(OnSaveCompleted, null);
> 
> void OnSaveCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>         {
>             Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     App.ViewModel.Context.EndSaveChanges(asyncResult);
>                     this.StatusMessage.Text = "Successfully saved
> changes";
>                 }
```

It is give me an exceptions, because this 
DataServiceCollection customers; is different from the Objects Customers in the Context.
I know it is probably happened because I did mistake in app architecture. 
My first thought was: to create an Oblect "CustomerLocal" and inherit from the Customer, but this does not work. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you make your additional property internal the SaveChanges should ignore it.

Comment: Yes, your right, I can do it, but I have mention before, I need to bind this property to the Silverlight, in XAML file:`<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AddressLocal}" 
                                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
`Have you any other ideas?